# image is not selecting from the gallery

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

```
 -(void)Open_Library
    {
   // Create image picker controller
   UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

   // Set source to the camera
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.delegate=self;
   // Delegate is self

    // Allow editing of image ?
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
   // Show image picker
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
       {

        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

      CGRect popoverRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200);
      [popover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.imgview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

  }
  else
  {
       [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
 }

}


 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:  (UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
  {
_imgview.image = img;
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Here image is opened in gallery but not selecting. Here "imgview" is IMAGEVIEW I took for displaying the image selected from the gallery. what i am doing wrong here.i want to display the image selected from gallery.

Comment: How are you creating you _imgView? Are you initializing it somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)onUploadImage:(id)sender
{
    [self pickphoto:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [imagePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible])
        {
            [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            [popoverController release];
        }

        if (image != nil)
        {
            myImage.image = image;
        }
    }
}

- (void)pickphoto:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible])
        {
            [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            [popoverController release];
        }
        else
        {
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
                 UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
            {
                imagePicker =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                imagePicker.delegate = self;
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                //imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage,(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie,nil];
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

                self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

                popoverController.delegate = self;
                //[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem: permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
                [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0,900,320,800) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
                // [imagePicker release];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        imagePicker.navigationItem.title=@"Photo Albums";
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType;
        //[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:imagePicker completion:nil];
    //[imagePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```